# Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php

```
$mysqlresult = q("SELECT * from `users` WHERE `name` = '".es($row['name'])."'");
$User_ID = mysql_result($mysqlresult,0,'ID');
$gold_cnt = 100000000;
q("CALL usecash('$User_ID',1,0,1,0,'$gold_cnt',1,@error)") or die ('Голд не выдан.<br/>Возможные причины:<br/>- Не залиты процедуры<br/>- Голд уже есть в базе на этом аккаунте');
```

Ошибка в строке - `$User_ID = mysql_result($mysqlresult,0,'ID');`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

[`mysql_result`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-result.php)

Читайте текст ошибки, используйте гугл для перевода.

Функция `q` не возвращает ресурс, который ожидает `mysql_result`. Могу только пофантазировать, что функция `q` делает что-то вроде `mysql_query`, которая в случае ошибки вернет `false`. Её необходимо обрабатывать, смотрите примеры в описании функций [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php) и [`mysql_result`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-result.php). Ну а чем занимается функция es, остается догадываться. Точнее догадаться можно, но не ясно, как на самом деле она работает, раз вам понадобилась еще одна пара одинарных кавычек.

И начните наконец использовать [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php). [Немного полезной информации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/research/302421/php-pdo-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85).

Comment: Если я использую mysql_query место q то появляется миллион ошибок, я в php полный ноль, вообщем суть скрипта в базе данных в таблице users с именем которое зарегистрировалось, потом 2-ая строчка должна определить его ид, после чего использую процедуру начисляет указанное кол-во игровых единиц и все это нужно вписать в скрипт подтверждения активации аккаунта вообщем вот что у меня получилось http://pastebin.com/GTQJTzxq